# Как работать со своей отдельной веткой в репозитории?

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull

До этого дня работал в отдельном репозитории и сегодня поступила команда, что для меня открыт branch от общего проекта, и мне надо туда перейти и мержить.

Я создал у себя новый branch, перешел туда и сделал pull от общего проекта, и тут у меня смешались файлы.

Как вообще в таком случае поступать надо? Клонировать весь проект и работать с теми файлами, которые тебе предназначены, или как только свою ветку клонировать или pull-ить?

И потом еще как push-ить именно в свою ветку?

Comment: пройдите дома курс вида [git howto](http://githowto.com/ru).

Comment: Во общем планирую так, клонировать удаленную репозиторию в целом т.е. весь проект затем git fetch && git checkout branchName и дальше работать как обычно и сделанную задачу пушить)

Comment: Ваша ветка ведь находиться на каком то удаленном сервере? Для начала нужно сделать правильно чекаут

    git checkout -t origin/release

и с удаленного репозитория будет скопирована ветка release.  Дальше с ней можно работать как обычно. комитить. А потом делать git pull (если с веткой работают другие люди) и git push (что бы отправить данные в ветку). Тут есть мелкое различие, git pull/push без параметров может отправлять не все ветки (тем более, в 1.7 это немного перевернули). Поэтому лучше указать ветку явно. Ещё команду merge изучить нужно будет.

Comment: Я так понимаю, ТС сделал следующее: у него был локальный репозиторий A. Потом он сделал "git pull B", где B -- совершенно другой репозиторий, никак не связанный с A. Соответственно у него случился merge двух веток из разных репозиториев ("смешались файлы вообщем бардак. смешались файлы вообщем бардак"). @bemulima, я прав?

Comment: @KoVadim, да ветка удаленная, мне разрешено работать только с папкой forMe и ветка еще есть branchForMe, попробовал клонировать весь проект, получилось, от туда перехожу на свою ветку так git fetch && git checkout branchForMe, но думаю так не правильно. Может есть возможность клонировать именно ту папку которое мне надо, пока ответа не могу найти

Comment: @dzhioev, бардак не у них а у меня. Да есть два репозитория "А" и "В", я работал с "В", которая содержит часть файлов от "А", теперь мне надо перейти в репозиторию "А" и там перейти в свою ветку и мержить с репозиторией "В"

Comment: 1. то, что вы пишите, чем то похоже на меркуриал. В git команда fetch просто вытягивает с удаленного репозитория, но не мержит/не вливает. Удобно, если планируете большой мердж, но сделать его там, где нет доступа к интернету.

2. В git нельзя просто так слить один каталог. Здесь работа с репозиторием в целом.

Answer (score 3):

предположим, что до этого вы работали с веткой `master`. и вас известили, что в основном репозитории для вас создали ветку `test`.

1. получите все обновления из основного репозитория:

   ```
   $ git fetch
   ```
2. после этого вы увидите ветку `test` из основного репозитория (вывод команды — ориентировочный):

   ```
   $ git branch -r
     origin/HEAD -> origin/master
     origin/master
     origin/test
   ```
3. создайте в своём локальном репозитории ветку (например, `test`), сразу же «привязав» её к ветке `test` из основного репозитория:

   ```
   $ git checkout -b test origin/test 
   Branch test set up to track remote branch test from origin.
   Switched to a new branch 'test'
   ```
4. теперь вы можете вносить изменения, коммитить их, отправлять в основной репозиторий командой:

   ```
   $ git push
   ```

   и получать обновления из этой ветки основного репозитория командой:

   ```
   $ git pull
   ```

   и «мёрджить» коммиты из другой ветки:

   ```
   $ git merge другая-ветка
   ```
5. в любой момент (ну, почти в любой) вы можете переключить свою рабочую копию файлов на другую ветку:

   ```
   $ git checkout другая-ветка
   ```

   и «вернуться обратно»:

   ```
   $ git checkout test
   ```